LLVM Address Sanitizer vs. `MALLOC_CHECK_=3`
In our CI jobs for our C++ project we run tests under both Address Sanitizer and MALLOC_CHECK_=3. I'm beginning to wonder whether the latter is even necessary. There are rumors flying around that the latter might check memory errors that ASan cannot, but I'm skeptical. For example, I heard that: "ASan can't figure out that you stomped over the allocator's private data structures."
Is there truth to these rumors? Is it possible to write a unit test that passes under ASan but fails under MALLOC_CHECK_=3? That would conclusively demonstrate the need for the latter ...

I am pretty sure it is impossible for any analysis tool to catch 100% of errors. So I think it is theoretically possible to have a situation where Address Sanitizer doesn't see any error, while MALLOC_CHECK_=3 does. But my guess is that the probability for that is so ridiculously low that it isn't worth it.

It'd be interesting to see what the rumours are actually saying. Do you have a link?

@TedLyngmo No link. Only the quote from a team mate I included in the question itself: "ASan can't figure out ..."

@LajosNagy In that case I suggest that you ask your team mate to provide support for the claim. The best thing would of course be if your team mate answered here on SO. I mean, why not?
